# The top header image is shaking/twitching when you start to scroll down, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

just when you start to scroll down with your mouse, the top header image shakes/trembles/twitches/ - I hope I described it good :)  [here it is.](http://demo.thrivethemes.com/tt/?theme=Pressive)
this is the demo of a theme, do you think it will do this on any install?

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are getting downvoted because you haven't described what you have tried and/or you haven't mentioned what browser you're experiencing this problem in. So, I'll try to answer this from my view in Chrome.

The biggest issue I see here is with the header flashing white before it animates to close. That can be fixed in `main_orange.css` by overwriting the header background:

```
#floating_menu.mff header {
    /* background: #fff; */
}
```

It may be worth looking at overwriting the animation in the `#floating_menu.mff.a60 header` css declaration as well.

Comment: Answering off topic questions is discouraged, please see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "*Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem*". Save your well-intentioned efforts for questions that meet the guidelines. This question was closed because it is too vague and doesn't give us nearly enough information for us to help, and was also asking us to use our mind reading skills to predict what it would do :)